# Zuul gateway not redirecting to given URL after security authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

My setup is a Zuul gateway server redirecting to a books handling API (Spring). The problem is it redirects fine when route is not authenticated, but **when I try to access authenticated route - it fails**. I'll add that accessing the API directly works fine.

This is my SecurityConfiguration at Gateway:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/book-service/books").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/eureka/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/success").and()
                .logout().permitAll().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

My Zuul properties at Gateway:

```
zuul.routes.book-service.path=/book-service/**
zuul.routes.book-service.sensitive-headers=Set-Cookie,Authorization
zuul.routes.book-service.url=http://localhost:8085
hystrix.command.book-service.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=600000
```

And this is my Zuul Filter at Gateway:

```
@Component
public class SessionSavingZuulPreFilter
        extends ZuulFilter {
    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository repository;

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpSession httpSession = context.getRequest().getSession();
        Session session = repository.findById(httpSession.getId());

        context.addZuulRequestHeader(

                "Cookie", "SESSION=" + httpSession.getId());

        return null;

    }
    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";

    }
    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now, at the client API I have this security configuration:

```
http.httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/books").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/books/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/books").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/books/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/books/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                //.antMatchers("/encrypt/**").permitAll()
                //.antMatchers("/decrypt/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
```

**I can access http://localhost:8085/books/1 after authentication (so the filter seems to work fine), but http://localhost:[gateway]/book-service/books/1 gives me error. Anyone can help?**

Answer (score 1):

use this stuff in your application.properties file,

```
#zuul.routes.admin.stripPrefix=false
server.use-forward-headers=true
management.security.enabled=true
zuul.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
zuul.add-host-header=true
```